# Sort LINQ query by child collection's child property?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have these objects:

```
public class Class
{
     public Guid Id {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public virtual ICollection<Schedule> Schedules{get;set;}
}

public class Schedule
{
     public Guid Id {get;set;}
     public virtual DayOfTheWeekId {get;set;}
     public virtual DayOfTheWeek {get;set;}
     public DateTime StartTime {get;set;}
     public DateTime EndTime {get;set;}
}
```

My current query looks like this, but I get this exception: **At least one object must implement IComparable.**:

```
    Repository
.Get(c => c.Schedules.Any(s => s.DayOfTheWeekTypeId == dayOfTheWeekId))
.OrderBy(e => e.Schedules.OrderBy(s => s.StartDateTime)).ToList()
```

when I set the times i always use the same day, because I need to show classes on certain days of the week. That is where the DayOfTheWeek object comes into play. This is how I am setting the times:

```
var schedule = new Schedule{
                           StartDateTime = new DateTime(1999,1,1) + new TimeSpan(9, 15, 0),
                           EndDateTime = new DateTime(1999,1,1) + new TimeSpan(9, 15, 0),
                           DayOfTheWeekTypeId = 1
                           }
```

**Update:**

Thinking about this, I guess I may want grouping...

Comment: The "Group By" samples for Linq are located here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to order by a *sequence*. What does that even mean?

It would make more sense to order by - say - the earliest event in the schedule:

```
.OrderBy(e => e.Schedules.Min(s => s.StartDateTime))
```

I don't know whether that will *work*, but it at least makes more sense. (It would work in LINQ to Objects. I have no idea about EF though.)

Comment: that is exactly what I needed, but I just realized that I am going to pull back all schedules regardless of day of the week. I'll have to modify my query so I am only pulling back the schedules for a given day.

Comment: once again you saved a life!